# Unable to resolve host address on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am struggling to use the wget on the Raspberry Pi. When I use the command, it sits on the address for awhile and then ultimately fails. I have tried adding in the 8.8.8.8 and the 8.8.4.4 name server to `/etc/resolve.conf` and that doesn't work.

Also it should be noted that this problem originated from me trying to run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and I get temporary failure resolving `raspbian.raspberrypi.org` and `archive.raspberrypi.org`.

Thanks to all who take the time to help.

Comment: Are you able to access the internet at all?

Comment: `/etc/resolve.conf` won't work. The file is named `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Hal, I am connected via ethernet but I also cannot get a search to load through the browser... the wifi is working on other devices in the house though so it must be a problem with the raspberry pi. The lights are illuminated on the raspberry pu ethernet port indicating a connection though. thanks